# Pyside: Opening a new window with picture

Tags: python, image, pyside, maya, mel

I have created a UI that can be launched inside Maya. My class for this window inherits from `QDialog`. I want to have a button that will open a `jpg` into a new window, and then it closes with another button. While this other window is open I would like to still be able to interact with the main window. Is it possible to do this? How would I go about launching this new window?

Comment: Read about modality in the documentation about QDialog. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get what you want. I tested it in Maya 2016.5 on macOS. Works fine!

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def loadSecondWindow(*args):
    window = cmds.window()
    cmds.paneLayout()
    cmds.image(image='/Users/swift/Desktop/scientist01.jpg')
    cmds.showWindow(window)

def deleteSecondWindow(*args):  
    if (cmds.window('window2', exists=True)):
        cmds.deleteUI('window2')  

cmds.window(width=200)
cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
cmds.button(label='Window with Picture', command=loadSecondWindow)
cmds.button(label='Delete Window', command=deleteSecondWindow)
cmds.showWindow()
```

[image]